# Elasticsearch client configuration - what is the right way to configure the client?

Tags: elasticsearch

Question on Elasticsearch configuration.

There is the -

1. `HttpClientConfigCallback`
2. `RequestConfigCallback`

In my case -
In the `HttpClientConfigCallback` - the connect timeout and socket timeout are set to `2_000` and `3_000` milliseconds respectively (this is set in the `IOReactorConfig`).

In the `RequestConfigCallback` - the connect timeout is set to `10_000` milliseconds and the socket timeout is set to `60_000` milliseconds.

At times I am seeing a `SocketTimeoutException` when performing some action on the Elasticsearch server. This is however happening at `30_000` milliseconds.

It is not clear to me as to where this `30_000` ms timeout is coming from. It is not one of the values that I set. If the `SocketTimeout` were to happen at `3_000` or `60_000` milliseconds - I can trace it back to my code.

1. What is the right way to configure these callbacks?
2. Am I doing something redundant or wrong here?
3. How do I find out where the `30_000` ms timeout coming from?

The code roughly looks like this -

```
httpAsyncClientBuilder
  .setConnectionManager
  (
   new PoolingNHttpClientConnectionManager
     (
      new DefaultConnectingIOReactor
      (
        IOReactorConfig.custom()
          .setIoThreadCount(ioThreadCount)
          .setConnectTimeout(2000)
          .setSoTimeout(3000)
          .setSoKeepAlive(true))

RestClientBuilder restClientBuilder =
                RestClient.builder(HttpHost.create(elasticSearchServiceEndpoint))
                    .setHttpClientConfigCallback(// the httpAsyncClientBuilder from above);
                    
RestClientBuilder.RequestConfigCallback requestConfigCallback = builder -> {

                builder.setConnectTimeout(10000);
                builder.setConnectionRequestTimeout(60000);
                builder.setSocketTimeout(60000);
                return builder;
            };

restClientBuilder.setRequestConfigCallback(requestConfigCallback);

new RestHighLevelClient(restClientBuilder)
```